# iPhone calendar with multiple calendars - only one is selected to display

Tags: calendar

I have the default iOS Calendar app setup with multiple calendar accounts - iCloud, Exchange and Google. Whenever I open the app, it shows only one of the calendars. I can select them, select holidays and birthdays, then close the config, after which all calendar events are shown. Then if I close the app, reopen and change to a different date, all the events for the other calendars disappear. This is not workable.

**What can I do to get all the calendars displayed, and have the setting saved properly?**

Comment: Do you also use other Apple devices, like a Mac, with this same setup?  What do you see when you go to iCloud.com and view your Calendar there, the same thing or all calendars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Under Settings>Calendar

[image: settings_calendar]

### Verify accounts connected to device

[image: calendar_accounts]

### On the Calendar app, zoom out and then click on calendars on the bottom

[image: calendar_months]

### Enable Accounts That you desire to be synchronized with your calendar

[image: active_accounts]

Comment: This is what I've tried several times. I don't know what changed, but now it remembers the setting so it seems fixed.